# Ridge Regression Centering Proof

Tags: regression, ridge-regression, centering

This is a ridge regression problem. The following two problems are equivalent:

$(w_t, b_\lambda ) = argmin_{w,b}\{\sum_{i=1}^m (y_i-b-w^Tx_i)^2+\lambda w^Tw\} $

$(w_t, b_\lambda )= argmin_{w,b}\{\sum_{i=1}^m (y_i-b-w^T(x_i-\bar x))^2+\lambda w^Tw\} $

where:

- $\bar x$ is the average of the input data.
- $\lambda$ defines a trade-off between the error on the data and the norm of the vector $w$ (degree of regularization)
- I'm assuming $b$ is a bias term

I can't work out why, mathematically, centering the data, has no effect.

Not looking for the answer, just a push in the right direction. Intuitively, I understand that offsetting each data point will have no effect on the final $w$ vector, because the relationships between the data points remains unchanged. Showing this mathematically, however, I'm unsure.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: a 'push in the right direction would be' that one doesn't regularize the constant term :) .  I think that answers your question.  A fuller discussion can be found in many places.  ISLR p 215 towards the bottom is one such place.

Comment: I don't think they are the same. If you change the predictors by demeaning them, there's no reason you should get the same weights $w$